# FUNCTION that parses a folder path and returns a table

Tags: t-sql

How to create a function that parses a folder path and returns a table?

The delimiter  will be the backslash `\`. Input will be a folder path  `FolderA\FolderB`.

Output will be a table with folders in sequence:

```
FolderName: FolderA  FolderB    
Level:      0      1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be generalized to the string-splitting problem. String manipulation in T-SQL is possible, but difficult to understand, because of the awkward syntax of complex expressions.

Itzik Ben-Gan provides all the tricks you need to solve this problem in an interview he gave to the [sqlservercode](http://sqlservercode.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/interview-with-itzik-ben-gan-author-of.html) blog.

#### A string-splitting function

Itzik provides an inline table-valued function for splitting strings, that, with a couple of modifications, will solve your problem:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_split(@arr AS VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  SELECT
    n - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@arr, n), ',', '')) + 1 AS pos,
    SUBSTRING(@arr, n,
      CHARINDEX(',', @arr + ',', n) - n) AS element
  FROM dbo.Nums
  WHERE n <= LEN(@arr) AND SUBSTRING(',' + @arr, n, 1) = ',';
```

This function allows you to split a comma-seperated string of elements into a positionally-indexed table. A query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_split('10248,10249,10250');
```

Produces a result set like this:

```
pos element
---- --------
1 10248
2 10249
3 10250
```

#### A auxilliary numbers table

The string-splitting function relies on an auxilliary numbers table. You may already have one of these in your database, because they useful for solving all sorts of problems.

If you don't have one, you can adapt another inline table-valued function that Itzik recommends for its efficiency, if not its clarity:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_nums(@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L5)
  SELECT n FROM Nums 
  WHERE n <= @n;
```

This function allows you to generate a table with the specified number of rows. A query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_nums(10);
```

Produces a result set like this:

```
n
---
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

#### A generic self-contained string-splitting function

By combining the string-splitter and the row-generator, you can make the function self-contained, by which I mean it works independently of other objects in the database.

By adding an extra parameter that specifies the delimiter character, you can make the string-splitter generic, becuase it will split a string delimited by any character, not just the comma.

You can replace Itzik's string'splitter with a modified version like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_split(@arr AS VARCHAR(MAX), @delim AS CHAR(1)) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) AS n FROM L5)
  SELECT
    n - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@arr, n), @delim, '')) + 1 AS pos,
    SUBSTRING(@arr, n,
      CHARINDEX(@delim, @arr + @delim, n) - n) AS element
  FROM Nums
  WHERE n <= LEN(@arr) AND SUBSTRING(@delim + @arr, n, 1) = @delim;
```

You can replicate the output of the original function by passing the same paramater as before and passing a comma as the delimiting character:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_split('10248,10249,10250', ',');
```

It produces a result set like this:

```
POS ELEMENT
1   10248
2   10249
3   10250
```

#### A solution to your problem

Now that we have a function that can produce a table for any delimited string of elements, we have a solution to your problem.

With the generic self-contained string-splitter in place, you can use this query:

```
SELECT
  Element AS FolderName,
  Pos - 1 AS Level
FROM dbo.fn_split('FolderA\FolderB', '\');
```

It produces a result set like this:

```
FOLDERNAME  LEVEL
FolderA 0
FolderB 1
```

SQL Server uses 1-based indexing for string manipulation and for sequences such as those generated by the ROW_NUMBER function, so it makes sense that a generic string-splitter should follow this convention.

Because you want the first folder in the path to be Level 0, the query subtracts 1 from the element position to get a 0-based index.

You can epxeriment with this solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56f98/2).